# Galois correspondence: Composite field and intersection of subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

Currently, I am trying to understand the proof of Proposition 7 of [Jyrki Lahtonen's introduction on linearly disjoint field extensions](http://users.utu.fi/lahtonen/linearly_disjoint.pdf).

Explicitly, we assume that $L$ and $L'$ are both finite Galois extensions of a base field $K$. Also, let $E/K$ be a separable field which contains both $L$ and $L'$. In particular, the composite field $LL'$ is also separable over $K$. Thus the extension $LL'/K$ has a normal closure inside $E$, i.e. $N$ is the smallest Galois extension of $K$ which contains $LL'$.

Here is the above mentioned

[image]

The line which I am currently questioning is the underlined one:

[image]

All I understand from *Galois correspondence reverses inclusions* is for two normal subgroups $G_1,G_2$ of $G$ which shall correspond to the extensions $N/M_1$ and $N/M_2$, we would habe the equivalence $G_1 \subseteq G_2 \: \Leftrightarrow \: M_1 \supseteq M_2$.

However, I do not really understand how this is exactly applied to the composition of fields resp. the intersection of subgroups. Could you please explain this part for me?

Comment: For a $K$-automorphism $\sigma$ of a finite extension $E’ \supset LL’$, $\sigma$ fixes $LL’$ iff $\sigma$ fixes $L$ and $L’$. Thus $Gal(E’/LL’)=Gal(E’/L) \cap Gal(E’/L’)$.

Comment: @Mindlack: I understand that if $\varphi$ fixes $LL'$, then $\sigma$ fixes $L$ and $L'$ as well. But why is the reverse true?

Comment: Because the set of fixed points of $\sigma$ is then a field containing $L$ and $L’$.

Comment: $LL’$ is the smallest field that contains both $L$ and $L’$; so by the correspondence, the subgroup corresponding to $LL’$ should be the largest subgroup that is contained in the subgroups corresponding to $L$ and to $L’$... that is, the intersection. Or you can do it the other way: the subgroup $H_1\cap H_2$ is the largest subgroup contained in $H_1$ and $H_2$, and so it must correspond to the smallest subfield that contains the fixed fields of both $H_1$ and $H_2$, which is their compositum.